# Draft picks already used

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have five individuals who all fill out a top 10 wish list for draft picks. They list their picks in order of preference (1-10) with `1` being the most desirable. When all five wish lists are received they are ranked 1>5. There are 32 total picks to choose from, of which none can be used twice.

So here's what I need an equation to do:

Automatically assign a pick based on the persons draft number and give them their highest rated pick. If that pick is already taken, move on to their next highest pick. There are ten draft rounds.

***Screenshot as is below***

[image: Screenshot as is below]

Comment: Please post what you have already tried yourself and add to your question the nature and cause of your effort's failure. Then someone here will help you fix it or suggest another way.

Comment: Have a search on here - there are similar problems where you can adapt the solutions.